# Page Navigation After login

Tags: react-native

```js
 if (res.response_code === 0) {
          debugger;
          console.log("need to navigate to homepage");
          return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <Home />
            </View>
          );
          //   this.props.navigation.push("Home");
          /* <AppNavigator /> */
        } else if (res.response_code === "1") {
          alert("Login Failed");
        }
      });
```

I am new to react-native I am facing an issue with navigation 
issue: I am using default react-native tabs app, After condition matched need to navigate to the AppNavigator screen but the console is printing but unable navigate to the required screen

Used this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");

```js
 if (res.response_code === 0) {
          console.log("need to navigate to homepage");
          return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <AppNavigator />
            </View>
          );

        } else if (res.response_code === "1") {
          alert("Login Failed");
        }
      });
```

Comment: Hi...
please make sure ! you have defined your "Home" in stackNavigator on main js file

Comment: Please show us all the codes you used.